# APACHE Spark executor can be pause and resume?

Tags: apache-spark, worker, executor, pause

I am new to spark and would like to know if spark have any Methods or other mechanism by which we can Pause the execution of executors(worker), and then can resume when needed.

Kindly provide the answer.

Thanks in advance.